# No converter for [class misc.contract.response.Response] with preset Content-Type 'text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8'

Tags: spring-boot, java-11, server-sent-events

When I return sse message from the java 11 server side written with spring boot `springBootVersion: '2.6.6',`, shows error like this:

```
No converter for [class misc.contract.response.Response] with preset Content-Type 'text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8'
```

this is the server side api define:

```
package com.dolphin.soa.post.controller.user.ai;

import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.SseEmitter;

/**
 * @version 1.0
 * @author: dolphin
 * @date: 2023-03-18 12:50
 */

@RequestMapping("/ai/stream/chat")
@FeignClient(name = "dolphin-post-service")
public interface IAiSseChatController {
    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    @GetMapping(path="/ask",produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    SseEmitter askStream(@RequestParam(required = true) String question);

}
```

what should I do to fixed this problem? The server side return json by default, the server sent event response was newly added recently. this is the `Response` define:

```
package misc.contract.response;

import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;
import lombok.Data;
import misc.exception.ServiceException;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 *
 */
@Data
@Schema
public class Response<T> {

    public static final String MSG_OK       = "ok";

    private String resultCode = ServiceException.API_OK;

    private String statusCode = ServiceException.API_OK;

    private String msg = MSG_OK;

    private T result;

    private Map<String, List<String>> validationErrors;

    public Response(ServiceException e, Map<String, List<String>> validationErrors) {
        this(e);
        this.validationErrors = validationErrors;
    }

    public Response(ServiceException e) {
        this(e.getMessage(), e.getStatusCode(), e.getResultCode());
    }

    public Response(String msg, String statusCode, String resultCode) {
        this.msg = msg;
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
        this.resultCode = resultCode;
    }

    public Response(T result)
    {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public Response() {
    }
}
```

Comment: You should post the entire stacktrace. I had a similar problem, will write a tentative solution soon.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem that I solved following this [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest) tutorial. The result was something like

```
@Configuration
public class EventStreamConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters (List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(new EventStreamHttpMessageConverter());
    }

}
```

where the converter is something like

```
public class EventStreamHttpMessageConverter<T> extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter<T> {

    public EventStreamHttpMessageConverter() {
        super(new MediaType("text", "event-stream"));
    }

    //implementation of the abstract methods...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the return type of your GlobalExceptionHandler, like this

```
@ExceptionHandler(AsyncRequestTimeoutException.class)
@ResponseBody
public SseEmitter sseTimeoutException(AsyncRequestTimeoutException e) {
    log.error("SSE TIMEOUT EXCEPTION:{}", e.getMessage(), e);
    return null;
}
```

Don't use your Response as the return type.